# Composed relations and simplicial complexes?

Tags: algebraic-topology, relations, simplicial-complex

Say you have two relations $R$ and $S$ on finite sets such that the composition $RS$ is well-defined. Each of these has a corresponding [Dowker complex](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108310/) (actually two, but they are homotopy equivalent). Is there any "nice" relationship between the Dowker complexes of $R$ and $S$ and the Dowker complex of $RS$?